# Why this is allowed and executing successfully?

Tags: c#, interface

Below is a sample code snippet, having 2 interfaces with exact same sign and return type. If a class A is implementing both interfaces that has same method signature, then why is this not conflict for compiler during method execution as which method to call because method is declared without explicit implementation of the interface.

```
interface IInterface1 { void Show(); }
interface IInterface2 { void Show(); }

class A: IInterface1, IInterface2
{
    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("j");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here really, why do you expect it *not* to work? In this case, if you have a variable of the class type, you can call the Show method, and if you have a variable of any of the two interface types you can call the same Show method. The same single implementation in your class covers both interfaces. If you want them to be separate, then yes, you will need to declare at least one of them using explicit implementation.

Comment: Why would it conflict for the compiler? Your class implements Show() for IInterface1 and Show() for IInterface2()... just on the same method

Comment: "from which one"? it doesn't matter. the interface-method is implemented, and there's no two conflicting _method signatures_. everything hunky-dory

Comment: Interfaces only say "classes implementing this will have those methods" and nothing else. Two exactly equal interfaces will have no conflict because, when using either, you'll find that the same method implements *both* at once, but  that doesn't conflicts with the requirements for interfaces.

Comment: Interface is like a promise. Both demands same method signature, therefore you need to implement it just once (implicitly) to fulfill the promise of either. If you must distinguish between those implementations, then it's another story. See [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

Comment: It's the equivalent in VB.Net (or MSIL for that matter) to saying `Public Sub Show() Implements IInterface1.Show, IInterface2.Show`

Comment: See also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036802/when-you-implement-two-interfaces-with-the-same-method-how-do-you-know-which-on

Answer (score 2):

Both Interfaces are saying : your class MUST implement the method "Show".

Your class is doing this, so it fulfil the requirement from both Interfaces. There's nothing there to conflict.

Answer (score 0):

> If a class A is implementing both interfaces that has same method
> signature, then why is this not conflict for compiler during method
> execution as which method to call because method is declared without
> explicit implementation of the interface.

It is not a conflict because this is the way compiler is programmed to interpret this kind of interface implementation where both interface contain a member with same signature. In this case, implementing that member on the class will cause both interfaces to use that member as their implementation. Following is sample implementation and output.

**Implementation**

```
using System;

namespace Console_Example
{
    interface IInterface1 { void Show(); }
    interface IInterface2 { void Show(); }

    class A : IInterface1, IInterface2
    {
        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Show() method in Class A.");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            IInterface1 interface1 = new A();
            IInterface2 interface2 = new A();

            a.Show();
            interface1.Show();
            interface2.Show();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Show() method in Class A.
Show() method in Class A.
Show() method in Class A.
Press any key.
```